# Removing duplication in a code fragment that performs multiple validations

Tags: java, refactoring

I would like to refactor this method to something without duplicates:

```
public class ContextValidator
{
    public static boolean validate(LoggingContext loggingContext) throws ValidationException
    {
        if (!isValidValue(loggingContext.getApplicationlevel()))
        {
            throw new ValidationException(UserErrors.UE_BAD_PARAMS,
                new Object[] { "Applicationlevel", "must be between 0 and 5" });
        }

        if (!isValidValue(loggingContext.getAuditlevel()))
        {
            throw new ValidationException(UserErrors.UE_BAD_PARAMS,
                new Object[] { "Auditlevel", "must be between 0 and 5" });
        }

        if (!isValidValue(loggingContext.getBillinglevel()))
        {
            throw new ValidationException(UserErrors.UE_BAD_PARAMS,
                new Object[] { "Billinglevel", "must be between 0 and 5" });
        }

        if (!isValidValue(loggingContext.getMetricslevel()))
        {
            throw new ValidationException(UserErrors.UE_BAD_PARAMS,
                new Object[] { "Metricslevel", "must be between 0 and 5" });
        }

        if (!isValidValue(loggingContext.getSecuritylevel()))
        {
            throw new ValidationException(UserErrors.UE_BAD_PARAMS,
                new Object[] { "Securitylevel","must be between 0 and 5" });
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidValue(int applicationlevel)
    {
        return (applicationlevel >= 0) && (applicationlevel <= 5);
    }
}
```

where `getXXXLevel()` is a method returning `int`. I tried to create map of method references to Strings: `Map<Supplier<Integer>, String>` `(ex: loggingContext::getBillinglevel, "BillingLevel")` and test them in `forEach()` - unfortunatelly `ValidationException` is checked so it cannot be thrown from forEach using my map types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire `if` into a helper method:

```
public static void checkAndThrow(int val, String name)
    throws ValidationException
{
    if (!isValidValue(val) {
        throw new ValidationException(UserErrors.UE_BAD_PARAMS,
            new Object[] { name, "must be between 0 and 5" });
    }
}
```

Now you can replace each `if` with a call to `checkAndThrow`:

```
public static boolean validate(LoggingContext loggingContext)
    throws ValidationException
{
    checkAndThrow(loggingContext.getApplicationlevel(), "Applicationlevel");
    checkAndThrow(loggingContext.getAuditlevel(), "Auditlevel");
    checkAndThrow(loggingContext.getBillinglevel(), "Billinglevel");
    ...
    return true;
}
```